# Winforms select filename for saving document

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms

I have some data and I would like to export it to excel. I did all the code, and everything is working fine, Now I want to save that excel file to the hard drive. I could do that too. but my problem is that I couldn't know how to allow the customer to set his/her own file name.

What I have tried:

```
FolderBrowserDialog brwsr = new FolderBrowserDialog();

//Check to see if the user clicked the cancel button
if (brwsr.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
else
{
    string newDirectoryPath = brwsr.SelectedPath;
    //Do whatever with the new path
}
```

the problem of that method is it is just allows the users to select the folder that the want the file to be saved to. I want to all the user to specifiy the path **and** the file name.

Any idea to help pleaes?

many thanks

Comment: You want the [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `SaveFileDialog` instead. This let's the user specify a path + filename. Check this out for more info: [SaveFileDialog on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`SaveFileDialog` is pretty similar to `FolderBrowserDialog`, so you can almost replace the existing code you already have ;)

### Specify File Type (EDIT)

Have a look a the [Filter property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*
```

Comment: how to tell that "saveFileDialog" is that I just need an excel file types? (xlsx, xls)?

Comment: I will be back after 30 minutes to accept your ansewr, Plus one

Comment: Filter is a property to be set not a method to be called!

Comment: @YoupTube my mistake, removed my comment.